# HAProxy inject proxy path into url internal requests

Tags: haproxy

I have a HAProxy configuration to map a route to a KeyCloak server that doesn't have any context.

If I call this server directly I must do something like `http://myserver.com:36765/`

This server will load its JS and CSS files with something like `http://myserver.com:36765/resources/rbr56/common/keycloak/web_modules/@patternfly/react-core/dist/styles/base.css`

This is how I've configured the route in HAProxy :

```
acl is_keycloak url_beg /keycloak /keycloak/

use_backend keycloak if is_keycloak

backend keycloak
  http-request add-header X-Script-Name "/keycloak/"
  http-request replace-path /keycloak/(/)?(.*) /\2
  server keycloak myserver.com:36765/ check
  http-response add-header Content-Type application/javascript if { var(txn.path) -m end .js }
```

I can reach the main page of this server thru the HAProxy using `http://theproxy.com/keycloak` but then the KeyCloak server starts to complain about it files because it still trying to load them without the proxy path:

`http://theproxy.com/resources/rbr56/common/keycloak/web_modules/@patternfly/react-core/dist/styles/base.css`

Note it don't add the "keycloak" path/context.

I read somewhere that `http-request add-header X-Script-Name "/keycloak/"` will do the job but it seems to not work.

I can't use the root context because another server is already using it.

How can I "force" the KeyCloak server (or any other like it) to add the proxy path to its internal links?